# How in Dart, instantiate an object with default modifiable list field

Tags: list, flutter, dart, initialization, instance

I have this class `User` and would like to be able to instantiate it with default modifiable field `phoneNumbers` as empty list, not as null or unmodifiable list.
I know that you can pass `const []` to constructor but this list will be unmodifiable.

```
class User {
  String name;
  var phoneNumbers;

  UserData(
      {this.name = '',
      this.phoneNumbers});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either initialize the field directly:

```dart
class User {
  String name;
  var phoneNumbers = [];

  UserData(
      {this.name = '',
      this.phoneNumbers});
}
```

or use constructor initializers:

```dart
class User {
  String name;
  var phoneNumbers;

  UserData(
      {this.name = '',
      this.phoneNumbers}): phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers ?? [];
}
```